# Error when using realloc for an array that store read int from file

Tags: c

I would like to resize the array when it reaches its max capacity. But error came up after i do ./a.out   Please help me...

```
Error: a.out: malloc.c:3574: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (mp_.pagesize-1)) == 0' failed.
```

code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
  int cap=5;
  int *arr = malloc(cap*sizeof(int));
  FILE *f;

  if((f=fopen("/home/file.txt","r"))==NULL)
    printf("You cannot open");  

  while(fscanf(f, "%d", arr++)!=EOF)
  {
    index++;
    if(index==cap-1)
      arr = realloc(arr, (cap +=1) * sizeof(int));
  } 

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `arr++` in your loop condition.  That means `arr` doesn't point to the start of the allocated memory anymore when you call `realloc()`.  That's going to end up with the error you're seeing.

Also:

1. Programming safety note:

   Don't call `realloc()` in the form:

   ```
   foo = realloc(foo, bar);
   ```

   If an error occurs, `foo` will be set to `NULL` and you'll leak the original allocation.
2. Nonidiomatic code note:

   ```
   (cap +=1) * sizeof(int)
   ```

   is a bit weird.  Why not `++cap * sizeof(int)`?  Or better yet, do it on two lines rather than cramming it all into one.

Comment: So the solution will be using a pointer to point to the arr and then read from the pointer right?

Comment: Just don't lose the pointer to the beginning of your allocation.  Make a copy and use that when calling `realloc()`, for example.

Comment: I did the following:
int *y = arr;

while(fscanf(f, "%d", y++)!=EOF)

so now i have a new pointer do the work, and arr is not change it original location. But instead i got a segmentation error :(

Comment: When you call `realloc()`, the base pointer to the array (`arr`) might change.  You'll need to adjust `y` to match if that happens.

Comment: But how do i ensure that y is not reading from the beginning again after i adjust the y?

Comment: Well, you have `index`, right?  Maybe you need to change your algorithm.

Comment: :) it works, i did :
y=arr+index;   after the realloc. So y points to the correct yet not repeated address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the `realloc` on the same address received fromm `malloc`, but you increase `arr` in `while(fscanf(f, "%d", arr++)!=EOF)`